# Confused Regarding a Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a bit confused about figuring out a solution for the Following:

I have 2 tables:

```
Days[id,Name]
```

And:

```
Schedule[Id,FrDocId,FrDayId,Timein,TimeOut]
```

Now what I want to do is extract values from Schedule to a datagridview,
Hence the Query will be ->

```
Select Id, FrDayId, TimeIn, TimeOut 
from Schedule 
where Schedule.FrDocID=@docid(Parameter);
```

Heres the confusion part I want to display the name of the day instead of its Id the FrDayId is a foreign key in schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the join statement for this.  Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT D.Name, S.Id, FrDayId, TimeIn, TimeOut
FROM Schedule S Inner JOIN Days D
   On S.FrDayId = D.id
WHERE S.FrDocID=@docid
```

The above code simply links all the rows from Schedule and Days where the `FrDayId` and `id` field match.  Then applies the where filter.

See [MSDN Docs on Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Aubert Thanks for posting this link to me!!